Springboot 3.2.4 - Idle timeout when using RestTemplate and JettyClientHttpRequestFactory
I am using **RestTemplate** to call an external service. One such request took more than 30 seconds and the springboot API call errored with the following message:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
    at org.springframework.http.client.JettyClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(JettyClientHttpRequest.java:120)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.java:70)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:112)
    at com.boomi.bundle.service.integration.hook.BaseRestTemplateInterceptor.intercept(BaseRestTemplateInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:88)

Is there a property for configuring the idle timeout? I have already set the following value
server.jetty.connection-idle-timeout=800000. Without this property is was timing out at 10 seconds
Any help is appreciated.
Requests made using RESTTemplate should complete if it is within the server.jetty.connection-idle-timeout limit

I tried creating the  restTemplate to specify the readTimeout but it did not help either
@Bean  RestTemplate restTemplate() {         return new RestTemplateBuilder()                 .errorHandler(new RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler())                 .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(REST_TEMPLATE_READ_TIMEOUT))                 .build();     } 
